# Meteor heavy tasks

Tags: node.js, meteor, background, cluster-computing, worker

I develop a small app for my company's intern usage. I need to run some specific heavy tasks in a cluster to keep the main app available for every users. I need to use Mongo and some shared functions. I'm trying to use this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool , but it's not working because it doesn't support imports.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
                                                              ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How can i do this simple task ?
I need params on my functions and if possible a callback to notice users when task as ended.

NB: I also tried https://github.com/msavin/SteveJobs..meteor.jobs.scheduler.queue.background.tasks but it doesn't fork the main app, so tasks are on the same thread and block main app.

server\main.js

```
appConfig = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("config.json"));

workerpool = require('workerpool');
workers = workerpool.pool(appConfig.directories.app + "imports/api/workers.js", {"minWorkers":1,"maxWorkers":3});
```

imports\api\workers.js

```
import {Clients} from "./clients";
function test(clientId) {
    return Clients.findOne({id: clientId}).name;
}
```

Comment: Add your TS file name and part of code please

Comment: When the cluster is called, it loads "workers.js", but it's not working cause of the import, and it seems i can't use require to make it works.

Comment: The import error is not related to the workerpool package but your meteor app code.

Comment: No it's absolutly not. My meteor app works great without using workerpool